# Using a variable in the address bar to display an image?

Tags: php

I have a little problem I can't seem to get my head around. What I'm trying to do is that when someone "http://domain.com/directory/ImgVariableHere" it will display the image on a php page. I know I'm probably going about this the complete wrong way and that's why I've come here. I'm a newbie to PHP so please forgive me. Here's the code I have.

```
<?php
$img="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

echo "<img src=\"$img.png\">\n";
?>
```

Here's the code it echos.

```
<img src="http://domain.com/directory/.png">
```

I'm probably explaining this really badly, ask any questions of you need to. Thanks. If you have a completely different and better way of doing it then please do tell.

EDIT: What I'm trying to do is kind of like Gyazo. They show their images on a webpage, I'm trying to do that but by using variables in PHP and I just can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: It appears to be working exactly as intended. The fact that you got `src="http://domain.com/directory/.png"` is exactly what you want, correct? Now just navigate to a URL that has the correct variable at the end, and you're set!

Comment: I knew I was explaining it really badly, rockerest. I know it echos what I want and all, but what I'm trying to do is make it display an image which is where I run into my other problem, it 404 errors when I enter anything else into the address bar because it tries to look for that in the directory but it isn't there.

Comment: The behaviour you describe is impossible given an input URL of `http://domain.com/directory/ImgVariableHere`. Therefore you have another problem, like `mod_rewrite` configuration, or you are omitting other information.

Comment: To get a little clarification, are you trying to mask image names with variables? Eg: /directory/abcdef ===> myFunImage.png ?

Comment: I'm trying to output an image onto a PHP page. But I don't know how I would get the variable to refer to the image in question without using something like the address bar.

Comment: Have you looked at $_GET ? You could just make the url http://domain.com/directory?img=imageVariableHere

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

Put this in .htaccess in the root of your document, and it should route all requests to index.php, then you just put the script above in index.php, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to have a RewriteURL with a variable in it.

So when you want this we can create a .htaccess which will reserve a spot for your variable. Example is like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteBase / #Maybe your in a subfolder? Change this to /yoursubfolder/secondsub/...
#Redirect all urls that begin with /image/ to image_shower.php?image=<image value>
RewriteRule image/(.*) image_shower.php?image=$1
```

This rewrite all the urls that begin with /image/ to the image_shower.php without showing the image_shower.php URL. It also sends the information in a GET variable. Which can be easily retrieve in PHP. Like this:

```
<?php

$img="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. '/' . $_GET['image'];

echo "<img src=\"$img.png\">\n";
?>
```

Hope this will help you go further!

Comment: This now works: http://domain.com/image_shower.php?image=test and displays the image just like I asked, however I would like to know how to get the image_shower.php?image=test part out because the rewrite rule doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @user3727561 are you working remotely or locally? Do you know if you have the mod_rewrite.so enabled in your httpd.conf? Also did you set up your .htaccess in the folder which contains the image_shower.php? And if you have a subfolder, you need to set it up in the RewriteBase